# After installin Reanimated 2 still get the warrning "If you want to use Reanimated 2 then..."

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated-v2, react-navigation-top-tabs

i m trying to use '@react-navigation/top-tabs' but it deppendes on reanimated 2
i installed reanimated 2 but still get the same warrning :

```
If you want to use Reanimated 2 then go through our installation steps https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation
```

**1-is it ok to just ignore the warrning by using:**

```
.ignoreLogs(['Reanimated 2']);
```

**2-if u have any other idea please help me**

thank you

Comment: Check this link https://github.com/PedroBern/react-native-collapsible-tab-view/issues/168

Comment: @Majidlotfinia thank you man but still have the same problem  the quetion is closed ... that link does not have the solution

Answer (score 2):

finally i solved this issue by install **react-native-reanimated@alpha**, do not use **react-native-reanimated@next**!

Answer (score 1):

You might get warnings related to peer dependencies after installation. They are usually caused by incorrect version ranges specified in some packages. You can safely ignore most warnings as long as your app builds.

Comment: How this answer is accepted.

Comment: it's from the documentation @Kelly

Comment: [link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project)

Answer (score 1):

Please try **react-native-reanimated@alpha**