# I am trying to use the @react-navigation/drawer but it was not working properly

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

This is my app.js code

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Home from './src/components/Home';
import Login from './src/components/Login';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
function App() {
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default App;
```

This is my dependency package

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.65.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2"
  },
```

Error

ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_ReanimatedModule.default.createNode')
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

When i try to start react-native this error comes...

Please any one help me and rectify me

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error.
Upgrading the react-native-reanimated version to react-native-reanimated@2.2.0 solved my issue

I used `npm install react-native-reanimated@2.2.0`, after uninstalling the previous version

Comment: Uninstall reanimated package and install version 2.2.0 But It shows the errorWARN  If you want to use Reanimated 2 then go through our installation steps https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation

Comment: This link can assist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68425674/after-installin-reanimated-2-still-get-the-warrning-if-you-want-to-use-reanimat

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my node_modules folder then `yarn install` then I installed `react-native-reanimated@2.2.0` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same / similar issues and had to struggle for 2 days to find the solution that worked for me. Sharing it with the hope that it might help someone else:

For the drawer-navigation (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator) to work properly we need to do the following:

(1) Install navigation-drawer using: npm install @react-navigation/drawer.

(2) Install react-native-gesture-handler and react-native-reanimated by:

```
     (a) For bare react-native: npm install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
     (b) For expo projects: npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated
```

(3) Add the reanimated plugin in our babel.config.js file as shown in the code below:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
};
```

(4) And finally start the project with -c flag to start afresh and not from cache: expo start my-app -c

This worked for me. Hope it helps you as well